# Alternative to modal operators (blocked autosave)?

Tags: python, 3d-view, operator

I am coding an addon, where a specific feature draws a small 2D overlay into the viewport via the draw handlers. While this works fine, I want this overlay to react when the user hovers the mouse over it.

I know, that getting the mouse position and reacting to it is possible by using modal operators. However, continuously running [modal operators block the autosave function](https://developer.blender.org/T77825) and users will not be able to have autosave running when they use the addon.

So, is there an alternative way, which allows to:

1. Track the mouse position while it moves?
2. Call a `context.region.tag_redraw()` for a `SpaceView3D` to update the viewport and redraw the 2D overlay?

**Edit:**
Unfortunately, a custom tool suggested below is no option, because I need the addon feature to run continuously without blocking other Blender features (like other tools, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments by @Crantisz, I was able to solve the issue. A keymap based on the `MOUSEMOVE` event enables mouse hover events for test regions without using modal operators (and, thus, without blocking Blender's autosave function).

Here is a working example (tested in Blender 3.0):

```
import bpy

# global variables for the keymap handling
keyconfigs_addon = None
keymap_view3d = None
keymap_view3d_items = None

class EVENTKEYMAP_OT_mouse_move(bpy.types.Operator):
    """ This operator checks for mouseover events """
    bl_idname = "wm.mouse_over_event"
    bl_label = "Mouseover Event"

    # DEFINE REGION OF INTEREST
    # define a region in which something should happen if the mouse enters it
    test_region_x = 0
    test_region_y = 0
    test_region_width = 512
    test_region_height = 512

    # a function that tests if the mouse is over the test region
    def is_mouse_over(self, mouse_x, mouse_y):

        if (mouse_x > self.test_region_x and mouse_x < self.test_region_x + self.test_region_width) and (mouse_y > self.test_region_y and mouse_y < self.test_region_y + self.test_region_height):
            return True

    def invoke(self, context, event):

        # make sure the operator is called under valid conditions
        if (context is None) or (event is None) or (not context is None and context.region is None):
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        # mouse position in current region
        mouse_x = event.mouse_x - context.region.x
        mouse_y = event.mouse_y - context.region.y

        # if mouse is over the test region
        if self.is_mouse_over(mouse_x, mouse_y):

            # DO SOMETHING HERE TO REACT TO THE EVENT
            print("MOUSE CURSOR IS IN THE TEST REGION!")

            # redraw the area (only required, if you draw something in the test region)
            # context.area.tag_redraw()

            # important to pass the event through, so Blenders internal event
            # processing is not blocked
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        else:

            # DO SOMETHING HERE TO REACT TO THE EVENT
            print("MOUSE CURSOR IS NOT THE TEST REGION!")

            # redraw the area (only required, if you draw something in the test region)
            # context.area.tag_redraw()

            # important to pass the event through, so Blenders internal event
            # processing is not blocked
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

def register():

    # register the keymap operator
    bpy.utils.register_class(EVENTKEYMAP_OT_mouse_move)

    # add a global keymap for the VIEW_3D regions
    keyconfigs_addon = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
    if keyconfigs_addon:
        keymap_view3d = keyconfigs_addon.keymaps.new(name="3D View", space_type='VIEW_3D')
        keymap_view3d_items = keymap_view3d.keymap_items.new("wm.mouse_over_event", 'MOUSEMOVE', 'ANY')

def unregister():

    # remove the keymap
    if keymap: keymap_view3d.keymap_items.remove(keymap_view3d_items)

    # unregister the keymap operator
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(EVENTKEYMAP_OT_mouse_move)

# start the script
if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done a similar feature by creating a tool in the toolbar. While the tool is active, it uses its own keymap which allows setting an operator on the mouse move event.

```
class draw_tool(WorkSpaceTool):
    ...
    bl_keymap = (
         ....
        ("mesh.preview_operator",
         {"type": 'MOUSEMOVE', "value": 'ANY'},
         {"properties": [("add_new", True)]}),
        ("mesh.preview_operator",
         {"type": 'MOUSEMOVE', "ctrl": True, "value": 'ANY'},
         {"properties": [("add_new", False), ("tool_color", (1, 0, 0))]}),
         ....
    )
```

In operator, as you understand, it is easy to make changes in overlay.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds interesting! I never worked with keymaps, but I will try it. Two questions though: 
1. Will this create a button in the toolbar or will it still be possible to invoke the tool from a custom button in the addon panel?
2. Will it be possible to have this tool activated all the time while the user uses another tool?

Comment: This is a tool in the toolbar. You cannot run two different tools at the same time. In my case it works well, I select the tool, and it shows where the block will be pasted

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that. Then, unfortunately, this is not an option for my use case. I want this to be continuously running without blocking any other functionality.

Comment: You may try to set up a keymap for the entire 3D view then

Comment: I will check this. Do you know any good resources to get started with keymaps (except the Blender Python API documentation)? Or, even better: could you provide a simple code example by editing your answer?

Comment: I'm not good at keymaps, sorry

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway for the hint!

Comment: Thank you for the keymap suggestion, this does the trick! :)